# Call the function in flask into Django screen

Tags: flask, django-views

I am a beginner to flask & Django here I have created my file as below

flask.py

```
   from flask import Flask, jsonify
   import requests
   app = Flask(__name__)
   @app.route('/<name>',methods=['GET'])
   def index(name):
        return jsonify({ 'out' : "Hello"+ " "+str(name)})

  if __name__== "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 import requests
 from django.http import HttpResponse

 def hello(request):
     return render(request,'hello/index.html')

def output(request):
    nm1=request.GET.get("name")
    if not nm1:
        nm1=0
    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/'+str(name)).json()

    return render(request, 'hello/index.html', {'msg': response['msg']})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action ="output" method="GET">
<label for ="name">Your number: </label>
<input  type="text" name="name">
<input type ="submit" >
</form>

<div>
  {{ msg }}
</div>
```

My requirement now is I want to call function in flask.py without giving '/name' in the approute and in my def function. Is there any way I can call that function dynamically.

Comment: Why are you using flask and django at the same time??

Comment: For my learning  I am doing like this from Django screen I am invoking flask URL and getting output in my Django screen

Comment: I maybe be wrong but according to me this is not something which can be done or atleast would be recommended. Flask and django both are backend framework and you can't integrate a backend framework with another backend framework. I would recommend you to learn one of them at a time. Maybe start with flask because it's easy to use but yet powerful

Comment: Actually I am creating a html file in Django as frontend then from that file I was trying to call flask by entering data in that html file

Comment: "Actually I am creating a html file in Django as frontend" sorry but it really don't make any sense. See this tutorial https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH it is a great flask tutorial for beginners

Comment: Okay sure..Thanks